# Suppose F is a family of sets that has the property that for every G ⊆ F, ⋃G ϵ F. Prove that there is a unique set A s.t. A ϵ F and ∀ B ϵ F (B ⊆ A).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, notation, proof-explanation

the solutions to this questions, 3.6.11, are in the suggested solutions in the textbook (How to Prove It, Velleman). However, I have some trouble understanding the question. Initially, I produced a simple example to get my head around the question:

G={{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5}}

F={{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{99}}

$\bigcup$G={1,2,3,4,5}$\in$F

Indeed, G$\subseteq$F $\implies$ $\bigcup$G$\in$F, but

B={99}$\in$F but B$\not\subseteq$A

So there is no set in F such that every other element is a subset it. I am sure I am interpreting this wrong, so can someone please highlight where my error is?

Thanks!

Comment: The hypotheses require that the union of **every** subset of $F$ be an element, not that one choice of $G$ work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If it works for every subset of F, should it not work for any choice of G and, in particular, the one I have chosen?

Comment: The fact that it works for one $G$ does not mean it works for all choices of $G$. Your $F$ does **not** satisfy the hypothesis: it is not true that*any* choice of $G\subset F$ will work. That's why the conclusoon fails: because your $F$ does not satisfy the premise.  Imagine a statement that says "If all student's name begin with J then everyone has an F grade. You say, "okay, here is a student named John. Why doesn't everyone have an F?" I say, "you need all students to have names that start with J". You reply "But if all student's name begin with J, then so does John's, right?"

Comment: (cont) Well, yes, but the fact that one student's name starts with J does not tell you they all do. I mean, there's airwick, which explains why "everyone has an F" doesn't hold.

Comment: I think I was incorrectly imposing modus ponens as I (incorrectly?) thought the premise was for all $G$ ($G \subseteq F \implies \bigcup G \in F$)

Answer (score 1):

We want such a set $F$ to have the following property: If $G$ is any subset of $F$, no matter which one, then $\bigcup G \in F$.

The set $F = \{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \{99\}\}$ **does not** have this property, since $\{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{99\}\} \subseteq F$ but $\{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{99\} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 99\} \notin F$.

The set $F = \{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}\}$ also **does not** have this property, but for a sneaky reason: $\varnothing \subseteq F$, but $\bigcup \varnothing = \varnothing \notin F$.

On the other hand, the set $F = \{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \varnothing\}$ **does** have this property. To see this, we need to verify it for *every* subset $G$ of $F$. In other words, we need to check that all 15 of the sets
$$
\varnothing, \quad \{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \quad \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \\
\varnothing \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \quad \varnothing \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \varnothing \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \\ \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \{2, 3, 4, 5\} \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \\
\varnothing \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \varnothing \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \varnothing \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5\} \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \\
\{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5\} \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \quad \varnothing \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5\} \cup \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}
$$
are elements of $F$. And they are!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I think my misunderstanding of the question was having an incorrect premise:

for all $G$ ($G \subseteq F \implies \bigcup G \in F$).

Instead, it's a statement about $F$ and its subsets:

$\forall F \forall G$ ($G \subseteq F \implies \bigcup G \in F$),

which means for every family of sets $F$, the statement $\forall G$ ($G \subseteq F \implies \bigcup G \in F$) is true. But, as you have shown, {{1,2,3,4},{99}}⊆F but {1,2,3,4}∪{99}={1,2,3,4,99}∉F. Therefore, a true antecedent and false consequent is a false conditional.